# Deleting records from SQL Server table without cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete-row

I am trying to selectively delete records from a SQL Server 2005 table without looping through a cursor. The table can contain many records (sometimes > 500,000) so looping is too slow.

Data:

```
ID, UnitID, Day, Interval, Amount

1   100     10   21        9.345

2   100     10   22        9.367

3   200     11   21        4.150

4   300     11   21        4.350

5   300     11   22        4.734

6   300     11   23        5.106

7   400     13   21       10.257

8   400     13   22       10.428
```

Key is: ID, UnitID, Day, Interval.

In this example I wish to delete Records 2, 5 and 8 - they are adjacent to an existing record (based on the key).

Note: record 6 would not be deleted because once 5 is gone it is not adjacent any longer.

Am I asking too much?

Comment: I'm not positive, but a set doesn't understand "adjacency" from what I recall from set theory. This may need to be done with a cursor.

Comment: How do you decide which rows to delete? What is the criteria, based on what field(s)?

Comment: It appears to be "sequential order" based upon the key.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know to delete record no. 2 and 5, but not 6 ? I could select all rows with the same (UnitID, Day) values and delete all but one - but that would delete records #5 **and** #6 (since #4 already is (300,11) .......

Comment: Please define adjacency. Can two rows with different UnitIDs be adjacent? Can two rows with differenct days be adjacent, for example Day 1, and max allowed interval with day 2 min allowed interval?

Answer (score 4):

See these articles in my blog for performance detail:

- [**`SQL Server`: deleting adjacent values**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-deleting-adjacent-values/)
- [**`SQL Server`: deleting adjacent values (improved)**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/04/sql-server-deleting-adjacent-values-improved/)

---

The main idea for the query below is that we should delete all even rows from continuous ranges of intervals.

That is, if for given `(unitId, Day)` we have the following `intervals`:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
```

, we have two continuous ranges:

```
1
2
3
4
```

and

```
6
7
8
9
```

, and we should delete every even row:

```
1
2 -- delete
3
4 -- delete
```

and

```
6
7 -- delete
8
9 -- delete
```

, so that we get:

```
1
3
6
8
```

Note that "even rows" means "even per-range `ROW_NUMBER()`s" here, not "even values of `interval`".

Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, UnitID INT, [Day] INT, Interval INT, Amount FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, 100, 10, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, 100, 10, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, 200, 11, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, 300, 11, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, 300, 11, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, 300, 11, 23, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, 400, 13, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (8, 400, 13, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (9, 400, 13, 23, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (10, 400, 13, 24, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (11, 400, 13, 26, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (12, 400, 13, 27, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (13, 400, 13, 28, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (14, 400, 13, 29, 9.345)

;WITH   rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (
                PARTITION BY
                        (
                        SELECT  TOP 1 qi.id AS mint
                        FROM    @Table qi
                        WHERE   qi.unitid = qo.unitid
                                AND qi.[day] = qo.[day]
                                AND qi.interval <= qo.interval
                                AND NOT EXISTS
                                (
                                SELECT  NULL
                                FROM    @Table t
                                WHERE   t.unitid = qi.unitid
                                        AND t.[day] = qi.day
                                        AND t.interval = qi.interval - 1
                                )
                        ORDER BY
                                qi.interval DESC
                        )
                ORDER BY interval
                ) AS rnm
        FROM    @Table qo
        )
DELETE
FROM    rows
WHERE   rnm % 2 = 0

SELECT  *
FROM    @table
```

**Update:**

Here's a more efficient query:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, UnitID INT, [Day] INT, Interval INT, Amount FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, 100, 10, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, 100, 10, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, 200, 11, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, 300, 11, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, 300, 11, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, 300, 11, 23, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, 400, 13, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (8, 400, 13, 22, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (9, 400, 13, 23, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (10, 400, 13, 24, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (11, 400, 13, 26, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (12, 400, 13, 27, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (13, 400, 13, 28, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (14, 400, 13, 29, 9.345)

;WITH    source AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unitid, day ORDER BY interval) rn
        FROM    @Table
        ),
        rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unitid, day, interval - rn ORDER BY interval) AS rnm
        FROM    source
        )
DELETE
FROM    rows
WHERE   rnm % 2 = 0

SELECT  *
FROM    @table
```

Comment: If your contiguous range of intervals is 2, 3, 4, 5 -- you need to delete odds and not evens.

Comment: @Matt: Need to delete even rows, not even values. Interval `3` will have an even `ROW_NUMBER()` of `2` in your example.

Comment: I get it now.  Looks like WITH/ROW_NUMBER is the way to go for this one

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible — but you may be able to get close. It appears you can *almost* do it by finding records with a self-join like this:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM
  table t1 JOIN table t2 ON (
    t1.unitid = t2.unitid AND
    t1.day = t2.day AND
    t1.interval = t2.interval - 1
  )
```

but the problem is, that'll find id=6 as well. However, if you create a temporary table from this data, it may be *much* smaller than your original data, and thus far faster to scan with a cursor (to fix the id=6 problem). You can then do a `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp_table)` to kill the rows.

There may be a way to fix the ID=6 problem w/o a cursor, but if so, I don't see it.

Comment: If you've already put the original select into a table variable, then you could use a WHILE instead of a cursor to fix the id=6 problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [WHILE statement](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3100621/T-SQL-Programming-Part-2---Building-a-T-SQL-Loop.htm), which is an alternative to the cursor.  That combined with [table variables](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) might let you do the same thing within a performance bound you're OK with.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, UnitID INT, [Day] INT, Interval INT, Amount FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, 100, 10, 21, 9.345)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, 100, 10, 22, 9.367)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, 200, 11, 21, 4.150)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, 300, 11, 21, 4.350)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, 300, 11, 22, 4.734)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, 300, 11, 23, 5.106)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, 400, 13, 21, 10.257)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (8, 400, 13, 22, 10.428)

DELETE FROM @Table
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT t1.ID
  FROM @Table t1
       INNER JOIN @Table t2 
            ON  t2.UnitID = t1.UnitID 
                AND t2.Day = t1.Day 
                AND t2.Interval = t1.Interval - 1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table t3 
            ON  t3.UnitID = t2.UnitID 
                AND t3.Day = t2.Day 
                AND t3.Interval = t2.Interval - 1
  WHERE t3.ID IS NULL)

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: This will delete only the first adjacent value. If we have `21`, `22`, `23` and `24`, this will delete `22` but leave `24`.

Answer (score 0):

Lieven is so close - it worked for the test set, but if I add a few more records it starts to miss some.

We cannot use any odd/even criteria - we have no idea how the data falls.

Add this data and retry:

```
INSERT @Table VALUES (9,    100,     10,   23,        9.345)

INSERT @Table VALUES (10,   100,     10,   24,        9.367)

INSERT @Table VALUES (11,   100,     10,   25,        4.150)

INSERT @Table VALUES (12,   100,     10,   26,        4.350)

INSERT @Table VALUES (13,   300,     11,   25,        4.734)

INSERT @Table VALUES (14,   300,     11,   26,        5.106)

INSERT @Table VALUES (15,   300,     11,   27,       10.257)

INSERT @Table VALUES (16,   300,     11,   29,       10.428)
```

Comment: @Ian: retried, it leaves rows `9`, `11`, `13`, `15` and `16`, deletes `10`, `12` and `14`. Isn't it what you want?